# New Folder not being Created

Tags: windows-7, windows

Windows Explorer (Windows 7) stopped creating any New Folders.  I don't recall changing anything and have restarted and shut down with no change.  Any suggestions?  I use Firefox and haven't had problems prior to the last day.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you mention Firefox in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening an elevated command prompt: Open start menu, right click and click *Run as Administrator*

Once the command shell is open, type out:

> sfc /scannow

---

I've got a rather drastic approach, but it's fixed someone else's problem so I might as well give it a go.

1. Open notepad and paste in the following text

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}]
>   @="CLSID_ExecuteFolder"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}\InProcServer32]
>   @="ExplorerFrame.dll"
>   "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
>   @="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder]
>   @="Folder"
>   "EditFlags"=hex:d2,03,00,00
>   "FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.Size"
>   "ThumbnailCutoff"=dword:00000000
>   "TileInfo"="prop:System.Title;System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemType"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\DefaultIcon]
>   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>     00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
>     65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,00,00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore]
>   "MultiSelectModel"="Document"
>   "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000022
>   "ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000021
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
>   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>     00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
>     65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
>     00,65,00,2c,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,\
>     2c,00,25,00,4c,00,00,00
>   "DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open]
>   "MultiSelectModel"="Document"
>   "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000010
>   "ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000012
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command]
>   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>     00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
>     65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
>     00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,00,25,00,4c,00,\
>     00,00
>   "DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers{F9DB5320-233E-11D1-9F84-707F02C10627}]
>   @="PDF Column Info"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\BriefcaseMenu]
>   @="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Offline Files]
>   @="{474C98EE-CF3D-41f5-80E3-4AAB0AB04301}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers{BD472F60-27FA-11cf-B8B4-444553540000}]
>   @=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\BriefcasePage]
>   @="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Offline Files]
>   @="{7EFA68C6-086B-43e1-A2D2-55A113531240}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew]
>   "Directory"=""
>   "IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
>     74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
>     00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,\
>     00,00
>   "ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30396"
>   "MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30317"
>   "NonLFNFileSpec"="@shell32.dll,-30319"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config]
>   "AllDrives"=""
>   "IsFolder"=""
>   "NoExtension"=""

2. After pasting the above commands, please click File on the menu and click Save.
3. Type in NewFolder.reg as the file name, select to save the file on the Desktop. Click Save.
4. Go to the Desktop, and double click NewFolder.reg. A dialog box will pop-up saying "Are you sure you want to add the information in fix.reg to the registry?". Click Yes to confirm.

Note: Administrative privileges are required to perform the above steps. Please click "Continue" when the User Account Control dialog-box appears.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't change anything, still can't create a New Folder in Explorer.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: On that note, can you create a folder using the command prompt. Navigate to your desktop:
C:/Users/[Username]/Desktop and try: mkdir "test01"

Comment: I've added a new method, try it out, and let me know about the results.